# How to create root node with xmlns:xsi but no prefix?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

What's the proper way to create a root node without the prefix, but have it display `xmlns:xsi="blah"`? Basically I want something like this:

```
<EDSCrate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="EDS_Crate_2010-02-10.xsd" version="0.95">
    <Whatever>
    </Whatever>
</EDSCrate>
```

However, I've tried many ways, it just won't give me a simple node without the namespace, and even if it does, it doesn't give me the proper `xmlns:xsi` in the attribute.

I'd like to avoid any hack like overriding the `ToString` and replacing the text myself in the `XmlWriter`.

```
string uri = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null));

nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", uri);

XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("EDSCrate", uri);
// at this point, it already added xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" without me doing anything
root.RemoveAllAttributes();
// but i want xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"!!
root.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", uri);
root.SetAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "EDS_Crate_2010-02-10.xsd");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string uri = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null));

var root = doc.CreateElement("EDSCrate");
doc.AppendChild(root);
root.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Whatever"));

var attr = doc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", uri);
attr.InnerText = "EDS_Crate_2010-02-10.xsd";
root.SetAttributeNode(attr);

root.SetAttribute("version", "0.95");
```

Comment: What the heck, so if i pass the uri as parameter via CreateElement, it would only put `xmlns:` but if I don't pass the uri, then it grabs it from the namespace manager and put `xmlns:xsi`?!?!

Answer (score 1):

I find using [Linq2Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) easier.

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

var xdoc = new XDocument(
                new XElement(
                    "EDSCrate",
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
                    new XAttribute(xsi + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "EDS_Crate_2010-02-10.xsd"),
                    new XAttribute("version", "0.95"),
                    new XElement("Whatever","")
                )
            );
var xml = xdoc.ToString();
```

OUTPUT:

```
<EDSCrate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="EDS_Crate_2010-02-10.xsd" 
          version="0.95">
  <Whatever></Whatever>
</EDSCrate>
```

Comment: I didn't try using Linq, but i'm sure your solution works too!